# How to use custom font in iOS ( Eg: Helvetica CY.ttf ) with Xcode programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, xcode6, truetype

- I am trying to use `Helvetica CY` font in my app. I have configured it as recommended by apple docs.
- The custom font shows up in dropdown in Storyboard, but **unable to use the same font programatically** in my class file.
- I have logged all font families available for the app, but "`Helvetica CY`" is not printed on console log.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you provide helpful details, no one is going to be able to help. Show relevant section of Info.plist and the relevant code.

Comment: Follow this tutorial, http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Comment: It's not printed, but included. It's just cyrillic version of Helvetika.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Its simple only. Its working for me in xcode6.1 too.

**Try using this [steps :](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/)**

**Step 1:** Include your fonts in your XCode project

**Step 2:** Make sure that they’re included in the target

**Step 3:** Double check that your fonts are included as Resources in your bundle

**Step 4:** Include your iOS custom fonts in your application plist

**Step 5:** Find the name of the font

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", family);

    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
        NSLog(@"  %@", name);
    }
}
```

**Step 6:** Use UIFont and specify the name of the font

```
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica CY" size:20];
```

Comment: "Make sure that they’re included in the target" thanks for that, dude

Answer (score 21):

Apple provides a set of fonts to customize our application and also allow us to add custom fonts.

Steps

1. Copy the font files(.ttf or .otf) to main bundle.
2. Add the file names into info.plist as a new array named "Fonts provided by application".
3. It is very important to add the post script name of fonts into this array. That means each font have the font name(with extension) and its postscript name in info.plist.
4. To find the Post script name,just open the Fontbook application in mac and then add the font file. After adding the font file into font book just look at the information tab of that font,there we can find the Post script name.
5. Using is pretty simple, use the post script name of the font,

   ```
   nameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaCY-Plain" size:22];
   ```

[image]

Comment: Please provide correct attribution when copying or paraphrasing large portions of text. This, for example, is a plain copy of http://xcodegeeks.blogspot.nl/2013/07/custom-fonts-in-ios.html.

Comment: Classic. Couldn't be funnier.

Answer (score 1):

I made the same mistake. The key is the answer above:

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames]) {
   NSLog(@"%@", family);

   for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family]) {
       NSLog(@"  %@", name);
   }
}
```

I included in my project folder the GOTHIC.TTF file.

And in my Info.plist I included GOTHIC.TTF in "Fonts provided by application".

**But surprise! The font it is not called "GOTHIC", but "CenturyGothic".**

```
[cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"CenturyGothic" size:24]];
```

Answer (score 1):

just go throw this link and follow steps.
it is having all steps 
http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is interested in Swift 3 code for getting fonts:

```
for family in UIFont.familyNames
{
    print("Family: \(family)")

    for name in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
    {
        print("Name: \(name)")
    }
}
```