# Unable to use TTF fonts in Project

Tags: ios, xcode, fontastic

I'm using ttf fonts for icon but I'm getting a problem to use them, in xCode right side of font it showing ? because of this ? I'm not able to use these fonts 
[image]

Comment: Go to your build phases, and in that copy bundle resources check if your fonts are added there. If not, add them. Also you need add an array entry named "Fonts provided by application" in  info.plist, and then you need to add your fonts name with extension as items to that array. For more info: http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Comment: The question marks to the side have nothing to do with your fonts being usable, they relate to source control - just indicating that the files are not being tracked, whereas the "A" means they have been added.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's related to source control and the question as it stands makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Select the particular .ttf in whose right side of font it showing '?' . Inspect the status of the particular .ttf in Source Control in File Inspector.

[image]

If not added Add the particular file. 
you can get step by step instructions from @SVMRAJESH [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667951/how-to-use-custom-font-in-ios-helvetica-cy-ttf-in-xcode-6-1-programatically).
Hope it helps. Happy Coding!!