# Exception while Assign Custom font

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, fonts

I am trying to add custom font in my application `GothamPro-NarrowMedium`
I added the `.otf` file in my project and in `info.plist` I added Fonts provided by the application and added to target membership. Now when I assign the font through Interface it works perfectly when I try to add it in `NSMutableAttributedString` I get the below exception

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary
>   initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from
>   objects[0]'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x181ad6fe0 0x180538538 0x1819bd9b4 0x1819bd824 0x100075dac 0x100073fa8 0x187c07ec0 0x187c07a9c
>   0x187f975f0 0x187f5bce0 0x187f58130 0x187e94950 0x187e869ec
>   0x187bfa648 0x181a849a8 0x181a82630 0x181a82a7c 0x1819b2da4
>   0x18341c074 0x187c6d058 0x10011ff44 0x1809c159c) libc++abi.dylib:
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

My code is

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
        paragraphStyle.alignment = _lbl_mylabel.textAlignment;

    NSDictionary *attribs = @{
                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName: self.lbl_ticketdetail.textColor,
                              NSFontAttributeName: self.lbl_ticketdetail.font
                              };
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText =
    [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text
                                           attributes:attribs];
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 3;

        [attributedText setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GothamPro-NarrowMedium" size:20.0],NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle}
                                range:cmp];

        NSRange plce = [text rangeOfString:place];
        [attributedText setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GothamPro-NarrowMedium" size:16.0],NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle}
                                range:plce];

        NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle1 = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
        paragraphStyle1.lineSpacing = 1;
        NSRange tkt_num_range = [text rangeOfString:STR_tkt_num_club];
        [attributedText setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GothamMedium" size:13.0],NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle1} range:tkt_num_range];
self.mylabel.attributedText = attributedText;
```

Comment: ***you are trying to put nil in the dictionary (which is not allowed). Since you are building the dictionaries with string literals those can't be nil.***

Comment: i think `self.lbl_ticketdetail.textColor` or `self.lbl_ticketdetail.font` would be `NIL`. Please check the values. Attribute dictionary shouldn't accept `NIL`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik As I had mentioned The font is properly added in .Plist

Comment: @LalKrishna If I use another font name it works so I think that is not the issue

Comment: sorry, your reply is unclear.

Comment: If when you use other font name, it works, but not this one hence it probably means your font name is wrong.

Comment: try to convert your font .otf to ttf . from here https://onlinefontconverter.com/ another solution :  set set target to that font .

Comment: @AJSanjay please try with UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham-ProNarrowMedium" size:16.0],NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle
and see whether it is working ?

Comment: @AravindAR Gotham-ProNarrowMedium is also not working

Comment: @LalKrishna [attributedText setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GothamBold" size:16.0],NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle}
                                    range:plce]; - >This code works and [attributedText setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GothamPro-NarrowMedium" size:16.0],NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle}
                                    range:plce]; - > this not works

Comment: @GeneCode gotham-pro-narrow-medium.otf is the font I downloaded and imported to my code

Comment: @KKRocks What you told is irrelevant

Comment: Basically the issue here is you are adding a nil object to a dictionary. It may be the font you are using. Have you seen the font name of it using `font book` I think I encountered the same issue where in the filename was different from the font name or something like that

Comment: Your issue is about the font: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984937/adding-custom-fonts-to-ios-app-finding-their-real-names https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667951/how-to-use-custom-font-in-ios-eg-helvetica-cy-ttf-with-xcode-programaticall etc.

Comment: i think you used `GothamPro-NarrowMedium` & `GothamMedium` (i mean the custom fonts you imported) programatically **only**. Are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crash occurred due to Attempting to insert `null` object to `Dictionary`.

I think you have problem with adding custom font to your project.

Please re-check

> 1. Add `.TTF` font in your application.
> 2. Add the key **`Fonts provided by application`** to a new row and
>      add each `.TTF` file names.

After this steps, I guess your `info.plist` may like this:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>GothamMedium</string>
    <string>GothamPro-NarrowMedium</string>
</array>
```

To find the Font PostScript name:

- Open Font book
- Select Font
- View -> Show Font Info (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>)
- Copy the *PostScript name*